# jQuery find elements with variable class names using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I am trying to get the number of elements that have a certain class name in them, the problem is, this class name has a variable at the end of it.  For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col width-33">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to write a jquery script to get the number of different `col`s there are and to get the number of columns with a class name of `width-xx` where XX can be any number.

```
$('.col').parent().each(function(i){ //The container could be anything
    var numCols = $(this).children('.col').length;
    var numColsWidth = $(this).children('div[class^="width-"].col').length;
    console.log(numCols, numColsWidth);
});
```

I'd like to output to be `3 1`, showing there are 3 total columns and 1 of them has a class named width-xx.

Just as the example above shows, I've tried using the CSS selector, but that doesn't give me anything (outputs `3 0`)

I've also tried playing around with RegExp, but I'm not sure how to add this into that

```
var widthClass = new RegExp("width-");
if(widthClass.test($('.col').attr('class'))){
    //do something
}
```

So, all I would like to do is count the number of elements that contain the word "width-" in the class.

Comment: Why don't you add another `has-width` class that you can search for exactly, instead of searching for a pattern?

Answer (score 3):

`$('[class*="width-"]').length` should do it.
this selector allows you to find any element that countains the word "width-" in the class

Comment: so simple...  Thank you!  I am using it like so: `var numColsWidth = $(this).children('[class*="width"]').length;`  It takes 10 minutes to "accept an answer" but this will be accepted then

Comment: This will probably solve your problem, but beware. If you also have a class like `fixed-width` it will match that as well.

Comment: How so? look closely at my solution.  there is a hyphen at the end of width, so it will not match fixed-width

Comment: good point.  I will probably just change "width-" to a unique keyword in which case, this should do fine.

Comment: I think he meant if there's a class like `this-width-fixed` it will call it out.  I think it can be fixed by saying `$('[class*=" width-"]')` with a space infront of the width

Comment: The only way that it will match is if you have any other classes that have width with a hyphen after it.  I will agree with Barmar in saying that best practices indcate you should create your own class and search for that rather than pattern matching though, :)

Comment: @ntgCleaner you can see all the different kind of selectors here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it has addressed your question adequately.  Thanks!